# Which is the difference between the tick symbol U+2713 and U+2714

Tags: unicode, symbols

Appart from the visual aspect... do those tick symbols have any different semantics?

I mean: One is thin and the other bold. But... any special meaning for one or the other? Or it is just a matter of using one graphical aspect or another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike the majority of characters in Unicode, the Dingbats range U+27xx have no particular semantic content. The 'heavy' check mark has no meaning beyond 'a check mark that is visually bolder than the other one'; contrast this with the 'bold' letters in plane that have a mathematical meaning.

This range of characters comes from the symbol font Zapf Dingbats. Symbol fonts are visual in nature and don't fit well in Unicode, but Zapf Dingbats has historical significance as a one of the PostScript core font set guaranteed to be available on PS printers. Subsequently characters from Zapf Dingbats have commonly been used in document interchange, making it worthwhile to standardise them.

Answer (score 4):

> Appart from the visual aspect.

There's no appart here, the visual aspect is King in Unicode.  U+2713 is a check mark.  U+2714 is a heavy check mark.  It should appear as a bolder version of U+2713 if you have a decent font.

These codepoints are in a group named Dingbats, a group of typographical symbols.  Chess pieces, arrows, asterisks, that sort of thing.  There's no semantic meaning attached to them.  It is just heavier.